# Angular 2 show and hide scroll button

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a button that shows up on the right corner when I make the first scroll down move. I want to make my button disappear after I scroll up on the page.
How can I do this? 
So far, my typescript function track($event:any){} looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    host: {'(window:scroll)': 'track($event)'}
})


export class DirectSearchComponent{
    showScrollButton:boolean=false;
    beginY: any;


constructor() {}

 track($event:any) {
    console.debug("Scroll Event", $event);
    if (this.beginY == undefined || this.beginY != null) {
        if (this.beginY > $event.scrollY) {
            this.showScrollButton = false;
        }
        else {
            this.showScrollButton = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        this.beginY = $event.scrollY;
        this.showScrollButton = true;
    }    
  }
 }
```

And my html code for the button looks like this:

```
  <a href="#" class="scrollup">
       <button *ngIf="showScrollButton"  
           type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block pull-right" 
                   style="position: fixed; bottom: 10px; right: 51px; 
                           width:3%; overflow:auto;">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" ></i>
       </button>
     </a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this.beginY is not being initialized properly.

Import NgOnInit and in the NgOnInit method, set...

```
this.beginY = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
```

This should properly initialize your variable to the initial page scroll value.